# Using multiple inheritance, getting "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Here is my code. Which is an exmaple of multiple inheritances in pyton. But it shows an error. I want to create a program where single inheritance and multiple inheritance will be used. To do this, create a base class Employee. And from Employee create two classes Programmer and Manager. Now using multiple inheritance create a class DevManager which inheritate from Programmer and Manager. But when I wnat to create an object of DevManager class with proper parameter it will show an error. Below is my code, I can't find where is the error.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, ename):
        self.id = id
        self.ename = ename

    def showInfo(self):
        print("ID=", self.id, "Name of employee=", self.ename)

class Programmer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, language):
        super().__init__(id, ename)
        self.language = language

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()
        print("Development Language=", self.language)

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, department):
        super().__init__(id, ename)
        self.department = department

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()
        print("Department=", self.department)

# Define Development Manager class using Multiple inheritances
class DevManager(Programmer, Manager):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, language, department):
        Programmer.__init__(self, id, ename, language)
        Manager.__init__(self, id, ename, department)

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()

# Main
obj = DevManager("A101", "Rajib Menon", "Python", "Engineering")
obj.showInfo()
```

In this program it will not create an object of Programmer class. Following error shows to me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Home\.spyder-py3\multiple.py", line 41, in <module>
    obj = DevManager("A101", "Rajib Menon", "Python", "Engineering")

  File "C:\Users\Home\.spyder-py3\multiple.py", line 33, in __init__
    Programmer.__init__(self, id, ename, language)

  File "C:\Users\Home\.spyder-py3\multiple.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(id, ename)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'department'
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Programmer.__init__` instead of just `super().__init__` as the other classes do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Inheritance in Python - TypeError "missing 1 required positional argument"](/q/72034905/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. I put a new title here, but it could still be better.

Comment: *"it will not create an object of Programmer class"* -- That's not quite what's happening; you're not actually creating a `Programmer` object anywhere; the error is occurring when creating a `DevManager` object and it runs `Programmer.__init__`. I imagine you know this already, just didn't phrase it properly.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was because the way of `super()` function works
what it does is :  it calls the method from the next class in MRO (method resolution order).

the mro in this case is :

```
print(DevManager.mro())
[<class '__main__.DevManager'>, <class '__main__.Programmer'>, <class '__main__.Manager'>, <class '__main__.Employee'>, <class 'object'>]
```

what happens when you instantiate is the first `super()` function will run the first `__init__()` function of the first class in the `mro` list `Programmer` then the second `super()` function will run the `__init__()` function of `Manager` and so on
and you need to give the `__init__()` function its right data and you don't know what is the order of running multiple `super()` function so you need to add `*args , **kwargs` to each one and it will do its work

```py
class Employee:
        def __init__(self, id, ename):
                self.id = id
                self.ename = ename
                super().__init__()

        def showInfo(self):
                print("ID=", self.id, "Name of employee=", self.ename)

class Programmer(Employee):
        def __init__(self, id, ename, language , *args, **kwargs):
                print("Set Programmer attrs")
                self.language = language
                super().__init__(id, ename,*args,**kwargs)

        def showInfo(self):
                super().showInfo()
                print("Development Language=", self.language)

class Manager(Employee):
        def __init__(self, id, ename, department,*args, **kwargs):
                print("Set Manager attrs")
                self.department = department
                super().__init__(id, ename,*args,**kwargs)

        def showInfo(self):
                super().showInfo()
                print("Department=", self.department)

# Define Development Manager class using Multiple inheritances
class DevManager(Programmer, Manager):

        def __init__(self, *args , **kwargs):
            super().__init__( *args , **kwargs)

        def showInfo(self):
                super().showInfo()

# Main
print(DevManager.mro())
obj = DevManager("A101", "Rajib Menon", "Python", "Engineering")
obj.showInfo()
```

### another Solution

you can call `__init__()` from each Class to avoid the arguments problem

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, ename):
        self.id = id
        self.ename = ename

    def showInfo(self):
        print("ID=", self.id, "Name of employee=", self.ename)

class Programmer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, language):
        Employee.__init__(self,id, ename)
        self.language = language

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()
        print("Development Language=", self.language)

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, department):
        Employee.__init__(self,id, ename)
        self.department = department

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()
        print("Department=", self.department)

# Define Development Manager class using Multiple inheritances
class DevManager(Programmer, Manager):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, language, department):
        
        Programmer.__init__(self, id, ename, language)
        Manager.__init__(self, id, ename, department)

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()

# Main
obj = DevManager("A101", "Rajib Menon", "Python", "Engineering")
obj.showInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use named paramaters not positional at object creation.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, ename, **kwargs):
        self.id = id
        self.ename = ename


class Programmer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, language, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.language = language


class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, department, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.department = department


class DevManager(Programmer, Manager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Can Instantiate Any Class More Clearly.

```
# Main
obj = DevManager(id="A101",
                 ename="Rajib Menon",
                 language="Python",
                 department="Engineering")
obj_p = Programmer(id="A102",
                   ename="Monty",
                   language="Python")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, ename):
        self.id = id
        self.ename = ename

    def showInfo(self):
        print("ID=", self.id, "Name of employee=", self.ename)

class Programmer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, language):
        super().__init__(id, ename)
        self.language = language

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()
        print("Development Language=", self.language)

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, id, ename, department):
        super().__init__(id, ename)
        self.department = department

    def showInfo(self):
        super().showInfo()
        print("Department=", self.department)

class DevManager:
    def __init__(self, id, ename, language, department):
        self.programmer = Programmer(id, ename, language)
        self.manager = Manager(id, ename, department)

    def showInfo(self):
        self.programmer.showInfo()
        self.manager.showInfo()

# Main
obj = DevManager("A101", "Rajib Menon", "Python", "Engineering")
obj.showInfo()
```

In this modified example, the DevManager class uses composition by creating instances of the Programmer and Manager classes. This approach avoids the complexity of multiple inheritance and the diamond problem ( that result a logical issue with the method resolution order (MRO)).

Print:

```
ID= A101 Name of employee= Rajib Menon
Development Language= Python
ID= A101 Name of employee= Rajib Menon
Department= Engineering
```

Comment: But then a `DevManager` isn't an `Employee` or a `Programmer` or a `Manager`, so what's the point? Don't get me wrong, composition over inheritance is a great rule of thumb, but this doesn't seem like a good use of it. This structure means that a `DevManager` **has** a `Programmer` and a `Manager` (maybe working under them, conceptually), instead of **being** a `Programmer` and a `Manager` (which is the actual conceptual structure you want).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @wjandrea, i did give the answer with the composition method to just avoid errors that may occurs later, when multiple inheritance in diamond like ambiguity in `method resolution`, `attribute and method name clashes` (if they have the same names), `inconsistent state`..., those can lead to unexpected behavior.